# __NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, nsmutabledictionary

I m doing XML parsing through NSXMLParser.
But when it comes to didendElement of NSXMLParser it crashes sometime and give result sometimes.I couldnot understand where I m going wrong?

```
 arr3=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    drr3=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSURL *urlString2= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.XXX.YYY/services/SService.svc/Get"];
  currentURL=@"1";
/// calling the service url and getting the repsnse in array (arr3)

if([arr3 count]==0)
{
 currentURL=@"2";
    //calling another service url and storing in arr3.
}

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if(currentURL==@"1")
{
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"PWList"])
        {
            arr3=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            drr3=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        }
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"])
        { 

            drr3=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];        
        }
        srr3=[[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 

}
if(currentURL==@"2")
{
      if([elementName isEqualToString:@"WeeksList"])
          {
              arr3=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


          }
          if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Person"])
          {

              drr3=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
          }

          srr3=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if(curentURL==@"1")
{

   //some code 
     if([elementName isEqualToString:@"PWList"])
        {

            [drr3 release],drr3=nil;
        }
}
if(curentURL==@"2")
{     
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Code"])
            {

                [drr3 setObject:srr3 forKey:@"Code"]; //crashes at this line
                [srr3 release],srr3=nil;
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

when it comes to `[drr3 setObject:srr3 forKey:@"Code"];` gives me error " `__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance".`

Sometimes I do get the result.

What can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Where did you define drr3? It seems that the object is gone at this moment. That it works sometimes can be just luck because the object is not already deallocated.

Comment: I have defined it in didStartElement.I have edited my code.Can u please have a look and tell me .

Comment: no im not using.How can I enable it ?

Comment: you enable it in the build settings but this won't help: you won't crash but drr3 will become nil! you forgot to retain it enough. see my answer

Comment: @Sindhia: are you sure you are not releasing the drr3 before this statement ?

Comment: Yes I m not releasing it anywhere before this statement.

Comment: Eventhough I m releasing it Im doing it alloc again na.I m I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: I have already used drr3 and released it

Comment: _where_ did you release it? Post the code that shows where you release it.

Comment: @AmyWorrall the concept is first im checkng for a response from a service url and taking it into array.If this array count=0 then Im again allocating the same array and dictionaries.

Comment: I have just edited my code

Comment: Put drr3=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] in your viewDidLoad or "initCode" method

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this code. You shouldnt use `if(curentURL==@"2")` and instead use `if([curentURL isEqualToString:@"2"])`. Also before releasing you should check `if (drr3)`. You can try to use `@property` for `drr3` and `srr3`.